# disable scrolling to the left when it reaches a certain value

Tags: javascript, scroll

So I want to disable scrolling to the left scroll left reaches the maximum. But it can still be scrollable to the right.

Currently this is my code

```
if (width - scrollLeft < 400) {
  event.target.scrollLeft = width - 400;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution would be to handle this with css.
Just give the parent a max-width